# How do I discover the values for variables of an equation with keras/tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have an equation that describes a curve in two dimensions. This equation has 5 variables. How do I discover the values of them with keras/tensorflow for a set of data? Is it possible? Someone know a tutorial of something similar?

I generated some data to train the network that has the format:
sample => [150, 66, 2] 150 sets with 66*2 with the data something like "time" x "acceleration"
targets => [150, 5] 150 sets with 5 variable numbers.

Obs: I know the range of the variables. I know too, that 150 sets of data are too few sample, but I need, after the code work, to train a new network with experimental data, and this is limited too. Visually, the curve is simple, it has a descendent linear part at the beggining and at the end it gets down "like an exponential".

My code is as follows:

```
def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(66*2,)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['mae'])
    return model

def smooth_curve(points, factor=0.9):
  [...]
  return smoothed_points

#load the generated data
train_data = np.load('samples00.npy')
test_data = np.load('samples00.npy')
train_targets = np.load('labels00.npy')
test_targets = np.load('labels00.npy')

#normalizing the data
mean = train_data.mean()
train_data -= mean
std = train_data.std()
train_data /= std
test_data -= mean
test_data /= std

#k-fold validation: 
k = 3
num_val_samples = len(train_data)//k
num_epochs = 100
all_mae_histories = []

for i in range(k):
    val_data = train_data[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
    val_targets = train_targets[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]

    partial_train_data = np.concatenate(
        [train_data[:i * num_val_samples],
         train_data[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]],
        axis=0)

    partial_train_targets = np.concatenate(
        [train_targets[:i * num_val_samples],
         train_targets[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]],
        axis=0)

    model = build_model()

    #reshape the data to get the format (100, 66*2)
    partial_train_data = partial_train_data.reshape(100, 66 * 2)
    val_data = val_data.reshape(50, 66 * 2)

    history = model.fit(partial_train_data,
                        partial_train_targets,
                        validation_data = (val_data, val_targets),
                        epochs = num_epochs,
                        batch_size = 1,
                        verbose = 1)

    mae_history = history.history['val_mean_absolute_error']
    all_mae_histories.append(mae_history)

average_mae_history = [
    np.mean([x[i] for x in all_mae_histories]) for i in range(num_epochs)]

smooth_mae_history = smooth_curve(average_mae_history[10:])

plt.plot(range(1, len(smooth_mae_history) + 1), smooth_mae_history)
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Validation MAE')
plt.show()
```

Obviously as it is, I need to get the best accuracy possible, but I am getting an "median absolute error(MAE)" like 96%, and this is inaceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I see some basic bugs in this methodology. Your final layer of the network has a softmax layer. This would mean it would output 5 values, which sum to 1, and behave as a probability distribution. What you actually want to predict is true numbers, or rather floating point values (under some fixed precision arithmetic).

If you have a range, then probably using a sigmoid and rescaling the final layer would to match the range (just multiply with the max value) would help you. By default sigmoid would ensure you get 5 numbers between 0 and 1.

The other thing should be to remove the cross entropy loss and use a loss like RMS, so that you predict your numbers well. You could also used 1D convolutions instead of using Fully connected layers.

There has been some work here: https://julialang.org/blog/2017/10/gsoc-NeuralNetDiffEq which tries to solve DEs and might be relevant to your work.